# How to use data URI in tool-tip text JLabel?

Tags: java, html, image, matlab, swing

I build a small GUI in Matlab that embedded several jLabel. To explain the visualized string I'm trying to set an image to the relative tooltiptext but it shows red cross. what am I wrong?

```
jLabel = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JLabel',['<html><center>New variable']);
jLabel.setTooltip(['<html><img src="data:/image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAAQ0lEQVR4Ae3UoQ0AMAzEwO6/dIvLHRDpTsoABp8DAMDnDl9PgABg84jzkQsQsIeAnoBAPtLyogABAnwhAQIECBAAAA8G2o6A3D5IkwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="'])
```

Comment: Java Swing's HTML support is **very** basic. It does not support `data` URI's.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass this limitation?

Comment: Try extending the [`HTMLEditorKit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html). Disclaimer: It's not something I would spend time or effort on, so .. good luck!

Comment: Oh, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14996842/418556) shows how to convert between URI's & images.